# Рисование области на карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Рисую область на канвасе, перевожу в координаты, строю многоугольник. Все хорошо, когда у карты **zoom > 5**. В противном случае получается, что после того как нарисовал область, многоугольник сдвигается на карте. Подскажите, что делаю неправильно?

```js
ymaps.ready(function(){
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
  center: [37.61691485505143, 55.7517318022522],
  zoom: 2
 });
  var polygon = null;
  $('.chk').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      drawLineOverMap(myMap).then(function(coordinates){
       // Перевод координат из 0..1 в географические
       var bounds = myMap.getBounds();
       coordinates = coordinates.map(function(x){
        return [bounds[1][0] + (1 - x[0]) * (bounds[0][0] - bounds[1][0]), bounds[1][1] + (x[1]) * (bounds[0][1] - bounds[1][1])];
       });
       // Cимплифицирование линии - оставляем только каждую третью координату
       coordinates = coordinates.filter(function (_, index){
        return index % 3 === 0;
       });
       // Создаем новый полигон
       polygon = new ymaps.Polygon([coordinates], {}, {
        strokeColor: '#0000ff',
        fillColor: '#8080ff',
        interactivityModel: 'default#transparent',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        opacity: 0.7
       });
       myMap.geoObjects.add(polygon);
      });
    } else {
      if(polygon){
      myMap.geoObjects.remove(polygon);
            polygon = null;
   }
    }
  });
});


/* Рисование области на карте */
function drawLineOverMap(map){
 var canvas = document.querySelector('.draw-canvas');
 $('.draw-canvas').removeClass('hide');
 var ctx2d = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var drawing = false;
 var coordinates = [];
 // Задаем размеры канвасу как у карты
 var rect = map.container.getParentElement().getBoundingClientRect();
 canvas.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
 canvas.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
 canvas.width = rect.width;
 canvas.height = rect.height;
 // Применяем стили
 ctx2d.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
 ctx2d.lineWidth = 3;
 canvas.style.opacity = 0.7;
 ctx2d.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 // Показываем канвас - он будет сверху карты из-за position: absolute
 canvas.style.display = 'block';
 canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
  // При нажатии мыши запоминаем координаты и что мы начали рисовать
  coordinates.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
  drawing = true;
 };
 canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
  // При движении мыши запоминаем координаты и рисуем линию
  if(drawing){
   var last = coordinates[coordinates.length - 1];
   ctx2d.beginPath();
   ctx2d.moveTo(last[0], last[1]);
   ctx2d.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
   ctx2d.stroke();
   coordinates.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
  }
 };
 return new Promise(function(resolve){
  // При отпускании мыши запоминаем координаты и скрываем канвас
  canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
   coordinates.push([e.offsetX, e.offsetY]);
   canvas.style.display = 'none';
   drawing = false;
   coordinates = coordinates.map(function(x){
    return [x[0] / canvas.width, x[1] / canvas.height];
   });
   resolve(coordinates);
   $('.draw-canvas').addClass('hide');
  };
 });
}
```

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #000000;
 clear: both;
}

#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.hide {
  
}

.draw-canvas {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 display: none;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<canvas class="draw-canvas hide"></canvas>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="chk"> Рисовать</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

В коде, основанном на [примере](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_custom) из песочницы Яндекса всё верно. Но в нём используется упрощённая модель трансляции пиксельных координат канваса в географические полигона, не учитывающая искажения используемой проекции, поэтому неизбежно смещение координат. Особенно сильно это заметно на умеренных широтах и малых масштабах.

Чтобы избежать этого, стоит для начала определить глобальные пиксельные координаты верхнего левого угла карты:

```
GPC = map.getGlobalPixelBounds()[0];
```

А в единственной теперь функции преобразования координат сдвиг данных канваса относительно этих координат обрабатывать методом [fromGlobalPixels](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IProjection.html#method_detail__fromGlobalPixels):

```
var projection = myMap.options.get('projection')
// Перевод координат из пиксельных в географические
coordinates = coordinates.map(function(x){
    return projection.fromGlobalPixels([x[0] + GPC[0], x[1] + GPC[1]], myMap.getZoom());
```

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/go7dfLym/